# Trying to alert a message to limit data output

Tags: apex, soql

I am trying to say "There is a duplicate search result. Please try again".

If there is more than one output, how do I express?

Current SOQL could retrieve more than one output, so I am trying to block that occurrence.

I guess I am trying to find out **which object I need to use and how** to apply  a guard clause (in other part of APEX code).

Should I use RowList on this case? If the object I am looking for is "RowList", how do I express?

Here is my APEX code:

```
 public PageReference searchPatients(){                     

    if( !string.isBlank(mrn)){
        if (RowList.size() > 1){
            ApexPages.addMessage(
            New ApexPages.Message(
            ApexPages.Severity.FATAL, 'Multiple MRN found'
            ));
            return null;
       }
    }      

    String bind_fname = string.isBlank(fName) || fname.length() <3 ? null : (fname.left(3) + '%');
    String bind_lname = string.isBlank(lname) || lname.length() <3 ? null : (lname.left(3) + '%');

    RowList = new List<TableRow2>();
    TableRow2 tr;

    for(Patient__c con : [SELECT sfprn__c, 
                                mrn__c,
                                LName__c, 
                                FName__c,
                                (select SurveySelection__c.SurveySelection__c from SurveySelections__r) 
                                FROM Patient__c
                                where ( mrn__c =:mrn )                      

      or ( LName__c LIKE :bind_lname and FName__c LIKE :bind_fname )   
                                ]){                                    
        tr = new TableRow2();
        tr.sfprn = con.sfprn__c;
        tr.mrn = con.mrn__c;
        tr.lname = con.LName__c;
        tr.fname = con.FName__c;
        tr.SurveySelection = con.SurveySelections__r.isEmpty() ? null : con.SurveySelections__r[0].SurveySelection__c;

        RowList.add(tr);         
    }
    return null;   
}
```

Here is my VF:

```
<apex:page Controller="psw" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
    <!-- Search button-->
    <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">        
          <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!searchPatients}" rerender="msgs"/> 
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>

    <apex:pageBlockSection id="msgs" columns="1">
        <apex:pageMessages id="msgs" />     
        <!-- Input starts -->
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="MRN" />
            <apex:inputText value="{!mrn}"/>            
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>             
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="Last Name" />
            <apex:inputText value="{!lname}"/>            
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="First Name" />
            <apex:inputText value="{!fname}"/>            
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 
        <!-- Input ends -->

        <!-- Output starts --->
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!RowList}" var="c">
            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">MRN</apex:facet>
                {!c.mrn}
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">Last Name</apex:facet>
                {!c.lname}
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">First Name</apex:facet>
                {!c.fname}
            </apex:column>                         
         </apex:pageBlockTable>
         <!-- Output ends --->
```

Comment: If you can provide with an example it will be better to understand. Also, how data is coming from UI to this code snippet. I am talking about "mrn"

Comment: I added more code (in Apex and VF). I did not add the Apex code where it currently has guard clauses already. Thanks Santanu.

Comment: A bit confused. If you do not want more than one record why i it in a `<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!RowList}" var="c">`?

Comment: So. I am having a user to search by both MRN OR (FirstName and LastName). If user searches by MRN, it always come with one one output because it is unique.  But if user searches by FirstName and LastName, it is possible to come with more than one output. So, that is where this limit takes place.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment

> I am having a user to search by both MRN OR (FirstName and LastName). If user searches by MRN, it always come with one one output because it is unique. But if user searches by FirstName and LastName, it is possible to come with more than one output. So, that is where this limit takes place

So something like:

```
if(RowList != null && !string.isBlank(mrn)){
   if(RowList.size() > 1){
      ApexPages.addMessage(
            New ApexPages.Message(
                ApexPages.Severity.FATAL, 'Multiple MRN found'
            )
      );
   }
}
```

Comment: Getting this error:  System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
Error is in expression '{!searchPatients}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page psw: Class.psw.searchPatients:

Comment: Basic debugging my friend. The above is just a conceptual representation so you will have to incorporate into your code/logic...

Comment: Ok. I guess it is due to location where this guard clause located. Thanks. Let me try to figure out.